# Ignore createdBy and CreatedDate in update query

Tags: java

I am using spring r2dbc and ReactiveCrudRepository, How can I ignore `createdBy` and `CreatedDate` in the update query.

```java
@Data
public class Base {
    @Id
     private long id;
   
     @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
     @Column("created_on")
     @CreatedDate
     private LocalDateTime createdOn;
 
     @Column("created_by")
     @CreatedBy
     private Long createdBy;
 
     @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
     @Column("updated_on")
     @LastModifiedDate
     private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
 
     @Column("updated_by")
     @LastModifiedBy
     private Long updatedBy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Transient` annotation like this:

```
...
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
...
@Data
public class Base {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
  @Column("created_on")
  @CreatedDate
  @Transient
  private LocalDateTime createdOn;

  @Column("created_by")
  @CreatedBy
  @Transient 
  private Long createdBy;

  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
  @Column("updated_on")
  @LastModifiedDate
  private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

  @Column("updated_by")
  @LastModifiedBy`enter code here`
  private Long updatedBy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@InsertOnlyProperty` annotation from `org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.InsertOnlyProperty` as follows:

```
@Data
public class Base {
    @Id
     private long id;
   
     @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
     @Column("created_on")
     @CreatedDate
     @InsertOnlyProperty
     private LocalDateTime createdOn;
 
     @Column("created_by")
     @CreatedBy
     @InsertOnlyProperty
     private Long createdBy;
 
     @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
     @Column("updated_on")
     @LastModifiedDate
     private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
 
     @Column("updated_by")
     @LastModifiedBy
     private Long updatedBy;
}
```

`@Transient` is not the ideal solution because it will completely ignore the property during persisting. This means that the columns `created_on` and `created_by` will be `NULL` in the database after `INSERT`.